# Executing shell commands on a HTML gui - on local machine only

Tags: php, html, linux, shell, csh

So I'm working on an application of my own where i need to execute shell commands, and even execute csh scripts on button clicks.All the HTML code is doing is displaying results from some sensors i have set up on my arduino via firefox, so im basically using it as a GUI. The HTML page wont ever be online, its purely running on my own machine.

I understand that its not straight forward as having HTML run shell commands on a live webpage is a security issue, but i have been reading about being able to execute shell commands using php scripts, but as it is running on a standalone PC i dont know how to integrate it into running a command from a button click on the page.

Infact i have no experience in using php at all, and i wouldnt even know where to start getting it to run through my HTML code.

Help!

edit:

If not php, is there any other way i can run a command such as 'ls' from a button click on the html page?

Oli

Comment: It would be nice to be able to use HTML as a cross-platform GUI to command-line scripts. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible without running a web server on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exec` php [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), and execute your scripts like this `exec('/path/myscript.sh')`

But surely you have to setup your php/apache in a correct way. Just try to look for some basic web-server configuration tutorials.

Comment: Even though this is purely on my own machine? i wont be using a webserver, its just displaying in firefox for my own amusement

Comment: if you want to use `php` for executing your scripts, then you have to setup at least php/apache, and configure it, that's what I meant.

Comment: Configure it in what way? im very new to all of this, consider me a php and html noob. I have php and apache installed on my linux machine

Comment: To make a basic image of the stuff you can have a look here (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

The rest depends on your own requirements

Comment: It need not be elephants, if mice suffice: have a look at lighttpd.

Comment: nice way to say ;), the choice is up to OP

Answer (score 0):

php command `exec` should execute a command and retrieve standard output.

```
<?php
    $result = exec("wc -l /etc/issue");
    print($result);
?>
```

With that print command you can print any html-text, that will be inserted into the page the client receives and displays.  So simply surround that php-snippet with you actual web page.

Comment: All this is doing is printing a dot for me, is it as simple as `<html>    <head></head> <body class="page_bg"> Hello World! <?php $result = exec("ls"); print($result) ?>. </body> </html>`

Comment: Yes, somewhat like that.  To get some format into your output, you should most likely iterate your $result line by line and extend the print-command to include html-formatting for your output of `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

General idea, you can create a HTML form with buttons that correspond to specific shell commands ( I understand this won't be LIVE on the web, so the security risks might not be an issue).

From there, you would receive the form input in PHP (you can use a framework like Laravel which makes this much easier to handle frontend/backend communication - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests)

A quick example with HTML and PHP:

```
<form id="arduino" method="post" action="{{ url('arduino/control') }}">
                <input type="text" name="command"/>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>

<?php 
Route::post('arduino/control', function () {

$command = Input::get('command');
exec($command); 

});
```